# Close previous instance of function, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an api build on nodejs.
On receiving the first request from one user, I want to trigger a send email function that send the mail after 15mins. But if a new request is made for the same user in between those 15mins, I want to close the previous timer and restart the counter from 15mins.

Problem I am facing is that how to check if any previous call has already been made to the api.

One possible solution that I can think of is storing a flag in db, and update on each api call, which will tell if the sendEmail has been triggered for the user or not. But maybe I though this might also be possible with having a variable at runtime which store the previous state. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: How you are managing it to send email after 15 minutes? Have you added `setTimeout`?

Comment: Do you have a list of user objects in memory already?  Or only in the database?  Does this have to be bulletproof so that if your server goes down, then everyone still gets their email when the server comes back up?

Comment: @SonuBamniya Yes, I am using `setTimeout` to wait for 15mins

Comment: @jfriend00 I do have user objects in database, but I was trying for a way to do without using that. And currently no, not thinking or implementing it to be bulletproof

Comment: Then you can create an object and store the timeout for the user with unique key in the object and on processing the API, you can check if the value of that user exists in that object, if yes you can use `clearTimeout` to clear the existing timeout

Comment: @SonuBamniya Ok, so I would need to create a globalObject to store the details, right? So that I can get it in next api call as well.

Comment: Yes! You can do this way, without utilizing the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have some unique identifier for each user.  Then, you can just create a `Map` object that has the userID as the key and an object of data include a timer as the value.

```
const userEmailData = new Map();

function sendUserEmailWithDelay(userId, emailContent) {
    let userData = userEmailData.get(userId);
    // if existing userData, then clear existing timer
    if (userData) {
        clearTimeout(userData.timer);
    }

    // set new timer for 15 minutes from now
    userData = {userId, emailContent, timer};
    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        // remove our object from the Map
        userEmailData.delete(userId);
        // send the email here using userData to know what to send and to whom
    }, 15 * 60 * 1000);

    // put this userData object into the Map
    userEmailData.set(userId, userData);
}
```